# Differentiating nested functions, Differentiate unevaluated function

Tags: differentials

I have two functions

```
    G[x_]:=x^6;
    S[x_]:=G[x]+x^12
```

I would like to operate on S[x] with respect to x in three ways, where we take the differentiation as an example for an operator

1. Plug in G[x] in S[x] and then differentiate
2. Do not plug in G[x] in S[x] and differentiate, such that x^12 is evaluated, but G[x] is only evaluated symbolically to G'[x]
3. Do not plug in G[x] in S[x] and regard G[x] as a constant.

While 1. has an obvious solution, do you have an idea how to realize 2. and 3. **without changing the lines of code given above**, in particular without re-defining G every time?

I tried to build an operator consisting of different elements such as Unevaluated, Defer, Inactivate, Hold and Replace, but either `G[x]` gets plugged into `S[x]` or the differentiation is incorrect.

Can I give the function G[x] (temporarily) the Attribute "Constant" for 3.?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block) and [`Inactive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive):

```
S'[x]
Block[{G = Inactive[G]}, S'[x]]
Block[{G},
    G /: Derivative[1][G] = 0&; (* G is a constant *)
    With[{r = S'[x]},
        Inactivate[r, G]
    ]
]
```

> 6 x^5 + 12 x^11
>
> 12 x^11 + Inactive[G]'[x]
>
> 12 x^11

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ways to approach this. For 1:

```
s[x_] := g[x] + x^12;
g[x_] = x^6;
D[s[x], x]
6 x^5 + 12 x^11
```

For 2:

```
Clear[g]
D[s[x], x]
12 x^11 + g'[x]
```

For 3:

```
g[x_] = c;
D[s[x], x]
12 x^11
```

Comment: Thank you for your attempt, but it is important not to change G[x_] every time.